# Linq to Sql Sum with no records

Tags: linq-to-sql, error-handling, sum

I am creating a method that collects accumulated totals throughout the month. The problem is that there may not be charges for some of the items in a given month so no rows would be returned.

I can see how this would error with no data:

```
double fuelCost = (double)(from a in db.EquipmentFuelLogs
                           where a.wdEquipmentMainGeneralOID == vehicleKey &&    
                                (monthBeginDate < a.Date1 && a.Date1 < monthEndDate)
                           select a.TotalCost).Sum();
```

What is the best approach to detect no fuel transactions for that month and set the fuel cost to 0? Just do a try catch? [This article](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/09/linq-to-sql-entity-framework-pitfalls.html) spoke of the problem but no solution.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2456670/463425
  .Select(a => (double?)a.TotalCost).Sum();

Answer (score -10, accepted):

I added a catch to catch the error. I never found a different solution.

Answer (score 18):

The issue is because the where is returning no sequence therefor the sum cannot work, however if you use `.DefaultIfEmpty` before the sum it works fine.

```
decimal? orderValue = 
    orders.Where(ee => ee.Name == "SomeName").DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(s => s.OrderCost);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this next time I need to do this.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved:

```
decimal orderValue = orders.Where(ee => ee.Name == "SomeName").Sum(s => (decimal?)s.OrderCost)??0;
```